# git pull for upstream master only - is push required?

Tags: git, github

I'm at a point where I run `git remote -v` and get this:

```
$ git remote -v
origin https://github.com/<user>/<repo>.git (fetch)
origin https://github.com/<user>/<repo>.git (push)
upstream https://github.com/<owner>/<repo>.git (fetch)
upstream https://github.com/<owner>/<repo>.git (push)
```

I'm quoting from [Happy Git with R](https://happygitwithr.com/upstream-changes.html), *"Now we can pull the changes that we don’t have from OWNER/REPO into our local copy."*

```
$ git pull upstream master --ff-only
From https://github.com/<user>/<repo>
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.
```

Please ignore things are *"already up to date"*, and ignore my likely misuse of git language to follow. That said, here's my question:

If things above were not up to date, would the upstream  repo changes have been pulled into my origin `master` branch, **or** one of my origin `other` branches?

If upstream changes were pulled into one of my origin `other` local branches then I assume I simply issue the `git push` command to send anything from my origin `other` branches to my origin `master` branch?

I understand the answer is probably indirectly in something such as [this R packages chapter](https://r-pkgs.org/git.html) but after several read throughs I'd like a little clarification.

Comment: Removing the [tag:r] tag, since this question is completely about `git` operation and nothing to do with the R programming language (other than the material you are `git`ing is likely R code or talking about R ... which doesn't make a solution R-based).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we ignore misuse of language, [colorless green ideas sleep furiously](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorless_green_ideas_sleep_furiously). :-) Semantics matter, and if we don't agree on terms, we'll get miscommunication.  So there's a bunch of setup here before I finally get to:

> If things above were not up to date, would the upstream repo changes have been pulled into my origin master branch, or one of my origin other branches?

If you want to skip the setup, jump down a section.

I had a brief look at [the linked page](https://happygitwithr.com/upstream-changes.html), and it seems to be pretty good—but the phrase *pull the changes* is, I think, not a good place to start.  Git doesn't store *changes*.  Git stores *commits*, which in turn store files: whole files, intact.  There are no *changes;* these are just complete snapshots of *all* of your files, in each commit.  It would be better to say *pull the commits* ... but even then, *pull* is (in my opinion) a verb to *avoid* in Git.  If I were writing the page I'd go in an entirely different direction.

The problem here is that `git pull` does *two* things.  Each of those two things is sensible on its own.  The *second* thing is often necessary after the first thing, depending on one's work-flow.  But for what you're doing here, based on the linked page, it's often *not* necessary, because this is a somewhat unusual work-flow.

Besides noting that commits save snapshots (rather than changes), it's important to understand, in a sort of deep automatic sense, something else here.  Commits are actually identified by their *commit hash ID*, often called an *object ID* or *OID*.  A hash ID looks like `8dca754b1e874719a732bc9ab7b0e14b21b1bc10`, for instance: it's just a big ugly string, seemingly random, impossible for humans to remember.  Because these things seem random, Git gives us *names*—branch and tag names, mainly—that we *can* remember.  Each branch or tag name just stores one big ugly hash ID.  **Every Git repository gets its own set of branch and tag names.**  When you connect your Git repository to some other Git repository, in general, you'll *share* their *tag* names (and vice versa), but for branch names, the story is more complicated.

(People do say "changes" very often when they really mean "commits".  If someone says something and it's ambiguous—did they really mean *commits?*—it may be worth stopping and asking, to avoid getting colorless green ideas.)

This is also where `git pull` gets pretty complicated, and I like to break it down into its two separate steps.  Here are the two steps:

1. Run `git fetch`.  This connects your Git to some other Git.  The other Git may have commits that you don't; if so, your Git gets these commits from their Git.  Now you both have the same commits—or rather, you may have *more* commits, ones that they still don't have, but you *do* have theirs.<sup>1</sup>  Now that you have all of their commits, *your* Git updates your *remote-tracking names* based on the `git fetch` you ran.

   Since you have two remotes—`origin` and `upstream`—your own Git now has *two* sets of remote-tracking names.  One set is prefixed by `origin`, so we can call them `origin/*`.  The other set is prefixed by `upstream`, so we can call them `upstream/*`.  What your Git does with these is to try to keep *your* copy—your `upstream/master`, for instance—the same as *their* copy, which they are using as an actual *branch* name, like `master`.

   Your own `master` is *your* branch.  Your branch can drift very far away from their `master`, or you can deliberately make it totally different, or whatever you like.  Often, though, you might like to keep *your* `master` pretty similar to, or even exactly the same as, *their* `master`.  This is what gets us to the second Git command.
2. Run a second Git command.  The *second* command that `git pull` runs depends on a lot of things, including configurations you could set (and you have not shown your settings, but we can make good guesses).

   The two main commands here are `git merge` and `git rebase`.  Given what's shown here, you must be using the default, which is `git merge`.  Both commands will, in general, affect the *current* branch—the one you earlier specified with `git checkout`.<sup>2</sup>

   The exact actual command isn't too important, but for the merge case, it's `git merge [flags] -m "merge branch branch of url" hash`.  The *`branch`* and *`flags`* come from your `git pull` command, and the *`url`* and *`hash`* are things that Git figures out: the *`url`* is whatever the URL is for the *`remote`* name you give—in this case, `upstream`—and the *`hash`* is the hash ID your Git gets from their Git when their Git says *my tip commit hash for that branch is ____* (they fill in the blank).

   You have your Git ask their (`upstream`'s) Git about their `master`, so their `master` supplies the commit hash ID.  Your particular `git pull` command also has `--ff-only` in it.  This flag is meaningful only to `git merge`, which is why we can be pretty sure you haven't set up your Git to run `git rebase` instead.  What `--ff-only` does is to tell your Git: *If this operation can be done as a fast-forward, do it.  Otherwise, do nothing at all, by making `git merge` fail with a `fatal` error.*

---

<sup>1</sup>You can limit which of their commits you get, and some forms of `git pull` do this limiting.  In this case, you don't necessarily have *all* the commits you could get from them.  You *do* have all the commits you need for the one particular branch of theirs that `git pull` asked for.

<sup>2</sup>In Git 2.23 or later, this becomes `git switch`, which is the new main command for switching branches.  (I wish they would re-label this Git 3.0: this is a big change!)

---

#### What `git merge` will do

> If things above were not up to date, would the upstream repo changes have been pulled into my origin master branch, or one of my origin other branches?

We can't tell from what you've posted.  What `git merge --ff-only -m "..." hash` is going to do is:

- Find the *merge base commit* between your current commit—this depends on which branch you did a `git checkout` on—and commit *`hash`*, that you either already had (`Already up to date.`) or just got from their Git.
- Because you said `--ff-only`, make sure that this merge base commit *is* the current commit.  (If not, fail with the `fatal` message.)
- Then, because a fast-forward not-really-a-merge is possible, move your current branch name so that it points to the given *`hash`* and check out that commit, as if by `git checkout hash`, except that your current branch name remains your current branch.

Note that your Git will do this—will advance your current branch, whatever that is—*whether or not* your `upstream/master` was already up to date.

In other words, your `git pull upstream master --ff-only`:

1. Runs `git fetch upstream master`: updates your `upstream/master`<sup>3</sup> from `upstream`'s `master`, obtaining any new commits they have that you don't.  Note that the reason you specify this as `upstream` and then `master` is that you are telling your `git fetch` to (a) call up the Git at `upstream`, then (b) ask it about its `master`.  Once this call to the other Git is done and your `upstream/master` is updated, you'll generally refer to it as your `upstream/master`.
2. Runs `git merge --ff-only -m "..." hash`, where *`hash`* is the hash ID that your Git got from their Git and stuffed into your `upstream/master` in step 1.

Step 2 gets run as long as step 1 succeeds, even if step 1 makes no changes at all to your repository.  If step 2 succeeds, one of your branch names is updated, but *which one* is not predictable without more background detail.

---

<sup>3</sup>There are a few ways that `upstream/master` might not get updated.  One is if your Git is quite ancient: automatic updating of `upstream/master` when `git fetch` is run the way `git pull` runs it was new in Git 1.8.4.  The other is if you've configured `remote.upstream.fetch` is a particularly weird way.  I'm assuming here that (a) you have a reasonably modern Git and (b) you have not set an unusual `remote.upstream.fetch` value.

---

#### Pushing

> If upstream changes were pulled into one of my origin `other` local branches ...

Again, we've hit some terminology issues.  Aside from "changes" (which we already discussed), I'm not sure what *you* mean by "origin `other` local branches".  If you were on some local branch `X`, so that `git status` started out by saying `on branch X`, then at this point—because of the `--ff-only`—your branch name `X` would identify a particular desirable commit: the one that their Git, over at `upstream`, is calling `master`.

> ... then I assume I simply issue the `git push` command to send anything from my origin `other` branches to my origin `master` branch?

I have to do a lot of guessing about what you mean here, so maybe we have some colorless green ideas again, but: I *think* the answer to this is "yes".  Note that `push` is the closest thing Git has to an opposite of `fetch`: it's not *push and pull* but rather *push and fetch*.  The verb *pull* was accidentally assigned to mean *fetch and merge* in early Git, and now we're stuck with this weirdness.

Given that I didn't write the original page talking about using `git pull`, this next bit of advice may be a bit dangerous, but: the way *I* would do this is to not use `git pull` at all.  I would run:

```
git fetch upstream
```

which would update *all* of my `upstream/*` names, using the Git I call up at the URL I have stored under the name `upstream`.<sup>4</sup>  Then, after that, I would run:

```
git push origin upstream/master:master
```

which would use the `upstream/master` that I updated in my step 1 (`git fetch`) to update the `master` over on the Git at the URL I have stored under the name `origin`.

---

<sup>4</sup>If this step is repeatedly very slow due to picking up lots of commits on lots of branches, *then* I *might* use `git fetch upstream master`, to just update my `upstream/master` from `upstream`'s `master`.  In general, though, there's no good reason to limit which commits you bring in with a `git fetch`.  If you'll ever bring in the rest of the commits, you're just trading "faster now" for "slower later".

If this is all happening in a throwaway repository, used just for this one update, it's reasonable to make it a *single-branch* repository, with an unusual `remote.upstream.fetch` configuration.  But I doubt that's the case here.

Comment: Hi @torek and thank you for this comprehensive answer. Please pardon my flagrant use of incorrect terminology. The intent is to demonstrate what I do and do not know, in the hopes of alerting the answerer as to what I know, and what I _should_ know. And it worked great, as evidenced by your excellent post! Thanks